# @BeforeClass in TestNG is not executed in parallel with parallel = instances

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a testng factory creating test instances having single @Test method. With "parallel=instances" and thread-count = "10" specified in testng.xml, I expect @BeforeClass to execute in parallel. Whereas I see the @BeforeClass of other threads is blocked on execution till the current @BeforeClass execution is complete. i.e prints "In Before Class" in sequence with 2 second delay.

What am I missing here ?

Here is my test code -

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("In Before Class ::: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}


@Test
public void test(){
    System.out.println("In Test ::: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass(){
    System.out.println("In After Class ::: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)

Comment: Doesn't work. I am still stuck at this issue where in I am instantiating my webdriver in @BeforeTest method, and using that driver instance in @BeforeClass method. Please assume that the driver management is threadsafe.

When I run the test standalone, everything is fine. But when I want to run them in testng suite, that too with `parallel="methods"` , I get Null pointer exception.